# Julia backslash for sparse matrices

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

New Julia user here. By my understanding, if `A` and `b` are a matrix and vector, then the Julia operation `A\b` will

- raise an exception if `A` is singular,
- perform a direct solve if `A` is square and invertible, or
- compute the OLS solution if the system is overdetermined.

If `A` is a sparse matrix represented by an instance of `SparseMatrixCSC`, then either a direct or an OLS solve can be accelerated using sparse matrix algorithms. I'd like to know whether `\` exploits the sparse structure, or else what library tools exist for an efficient sparse solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does take advantage of sparsity. To see what method it uses, you can use `@edit sprand(100,100,.1)\rand(100)` which will show you that uses `lu` or `qr` depending on whether the matrix is square (skipping some special cases for triangular/symmetric matrices. further `@edit lu(A)` and `@edit qr(A)` will tell you that the LU goes to `UmfpackLU` which is a sparse lu solver and the `qr` goes to `CHOLMOD` which is a sparse qr solver.